# Warining:Failed propType: Invalid props.style key 'display' supplied to View

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I used style display property in react native app and it gives above error.

Warining:Failed propType: Invalid props.style key 'display' supplied to View

```
const styles = {
  hideRmoveButton: {
    display:'none'
  },
  showRemoveButton: {
    height: 20
  }
};`


<Button transparent style={okToRemove? styles.showRemoveButton : styles.hideRmoveButton} >
    <Icon name='trash' style={{color:'#999'}}/>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: none` does not work with react-native. Instead you can use `opacity` and set it to zero.

```
 hideRmoveButton: {
   opacticy: 0
 },
```

Comment: still it shows the same error `Warining:Failed propType: Invalid props.style key 'opacticy' supplied to View

`